# Boot Problems in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, display

I am having some trouble booting my Ubuntu on VirtualBox. When I first started the 
system, I got the black screen that gives you the boot options :

1. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.12-generic
2. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.12-generic (recovery mode)
3. Previous Linux versions
4. Memory test (metest86+)
5. Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
6. Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-10-generic (on /dev/sdb1)
7. Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-10-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb1)
8. Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic (on /dev/sdb1)
9. Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb1)

I tried all of the options but they all gave me a black screen afterwards and it did
not go anywhere. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try these :

```
1) Increase memory for your virtual machine.
2) Try downloading fresh Ubuntu copy
3) Try working with live CD on your VM.
4) If live CD working properly, try installing Ubuntu to your VM again.
```

Comment: But this worked for me before. It's just when I tried upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 (but did not managed to finish) and tried starting again that I encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

- During the update process(Ubuntu 11.10) it will prompt you to remove
  the previous installed versions and headers .So if you clicked yes
  then you can't use previous one (Ubuntu 11.04)

  -New updated kernel 3.0 requires high memory and RAM

  -Direct updating through online of Ubuntu 11.10 from Ubuntu 11.04 causes many problems

So reinstall a fresh copy again from ISO From windows using wubi installer and allocate some extra space for Ubuntu.